# RSA encryption performance 1024 bits key vs 2048

Tags: c#, performance, rsa, bouncycastle, encryption-asymmetric

We have a server side application which receives a very heavy amount of load in the peak hours of day. Currently we are using RSA encryption/decryption with 1024 key size and things are working well so far. We want to make it more secure by changing the keysize to 2048 bits and I wrote one tool to compare the performance and found that decryption is almost 8-10 times slower with 2048 key size. Our application is in .Net and we are using BouncyCastle library for all encryption/decryption stuff.

Is there a way to improve the performance for asymmetric encryption?

Comment: So why not using `System.Security.Cryptography`  ? It is much faster

Comment: will give it a try, thanks for sharing.

Comment: That's unexpected. With the algorithms Bouncycastle uses it should only be about 3-4 times slower. The same will be true for the algorithms in `System.Security.Cryptography` although they should be much faster.